# Not in scope : data constructor IsTriangle

Tags: haskell, module

Here is the module - Number1.hs

```
module Number1(isTriangle) where

isTriangle x y z = if x*x+y*y >= z*z then True
               else False
```

This is the main program Main1.hs

```
import System.Environment
import Number1

main = do
    args<-getArgs
    let a = args !! 0
    let b = args !! 1
    let c = args !! 2
    if (IsTriangle a b c) then return(True) 
    else return(False)
```

This error I get when `ghc --make Main1.hs`

Comment: p.s. `if something then True else False` is the same as `something`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `isTriangle` in Main1.hs, you call it with a capital 'I'.

Make sure your capitalisation matches as Haskell is case sensitive, and make sure functions start with a lower case character as this is mandatory.

**Edit - rounding up other errors**

Main1.hs:

```
import System.Environment
import Number1

main :: IO()
main = do
         args<-getArgs
         {- Ideally you should check that there are at least 3 arguments
         before trying to read them, but that wasn't part of your
         question. -}
         let a = read (args !! 0) -- read converts [Char] to a number
         let b = read (args !! 1)
         let c = read (args !! 2)
         if (isTriangle a b c) then putStrLn "True"
           else putStrLn "False"
```

Number1.hs:

```
module Number1(isTriangle) where

{- It's always best to specify the type of a function so that both you and
   the compiler understand what you're trying to achieve.  It'll help you
   no end. -}
isTriangle       :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle x y z =  if x*x+y*y >= z*z then True
                      else False
```

Comment: The variables you are passing in are not numbers, they are lists of chars.  I'll paste the proper code into my original answer.

Comment: Thanks. But It returns nothing. For exam `>Main1 3 4 5` - and no result

Comment: Yes, that's because your `main` function does not expect arguments.  As you haven't specified a function type, the compiler decides that it must be of type `IO Bool` as it returns a boolean.  To have it receive args, you must make it of type `IO()` which means you can't return a value in the same way you have.  I'll update the code to print "True" and "False" instead.

Comment: I personally would just use `print $ isTriangle x y z`

Comment: @DanBurton Yup, that's a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Артём to pass arguments to main in ghci as if they were passed on the command line to an executable, you can use 1. ghci> :set args arg1 arg2 arg3 and then ghci> main or, simpler, 2. ghci> :main arg1 arg2 arg3